Why doesn’t the English Horn play higher than the Bass Oboe here?
In Mars, Fig II, there's a large Db major tutti chord. Holst scores this with bass oboe playing concert F4 and English horn playing Ab4, concert Db4. I would expect to put the Db in the bass oboe and the concert F in the English horn. Is there any reason why this isn't done?


I noticed that if Holst switched the voices, the E.H. would be playing a tritone. Is that why?

Are you talking about the chord spanning for the last three measures of the quoted score? Would you write it explicitly in the question, to make it easier to read?

It's worth noting that a large part of the orchestra is playing 'C' against that chord. Whatever reason Holst had, it's not to avoid a tritone, several other instruments jump a tritone there. We can only speculate on Holst's reasoning, I think it most likely happened by chance. It's certainly not for acoustic reasons: those instruments will be inaudible in that chord.
